# Image Array is not getting set for the first time in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am initializing the locationImage array and imvalidFileState like this:-

```
const [attendeeWaitingTime, setAttendeeWaitingTime]     =   useState("");
const [defaultFetchTime, setDefaultFetchTime]           =   useState("");
const [locationImage, setLocationImage]                 =   useState([]);
const [invalidFileState, setInvalidFileState]           =   useState(true);
```

I have a file input object in the associated form:-

```
<Form.Item name={"uploaded_images"} label="Upload File">
   <Input type={"file"} multiple={'multiple'} placeholder={"Select Image"} onChange={(e) => changeFile(e)}/>
</Form.Item>
```

The definition of the changeFile function is like this:-

```
const changeFile = e => {
    const files = e.target.files;
    setInvalidFileState(files.length === 0);
    /**
     * Check for the file type
     */
    const regex = new RegExp('image-*')
    for(let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        if(!regex.test(file.type)) {
            setInvalidFileState(true);
            return;
        }
    }
    setLocationImage(files);
    setInvalidFileState(false);
    console.log("Files ALL OK", invalidFileState);
    console.log("Files", locationImage);
}
```

The function behaves a bit weirdly. When I am selecting any image for the first time, `invalidFileState` is displayed as true and the `locationImage` is displayed as empty. However, from second time onwards, the values are displayed properly.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-does-calling-react-setstate-method-not-mutate-the-state-immediately

Comment: use your file change method in useState

Answer (score 0):

`useState` hook is asynchronous, and will not be reflected immediately. to perform an action on state update, you need to use the **useEffect** hook.

pass `changeFile`  as an argument to  `useEffect`  and

```
useEffect(() => {
  //your changeFile   function   
}, [locationImage]); / tells useEffect  to only trigger when locationImage changes
```